# Powershell: Child Property Deflation

Tags: powershell

Not sure if "deflating" is the right term, but I was wondering if there's a nicer way to specify that you only want to return a selection of an object's children's properties whilst using `Select-Object`? I'm using Powershell v5.

Here's a fully working example - the `$test` variable is hard coded here for demonstration purposes; in my use-case, the `$test` array is being returned from an API. I want to remove the `name` property from the `testChild` object during the projection.

The only way I could figure out how to do this is by using a foreach loop whilst piping into `$result`, then re-creating each child object and setting only the required properties, but it feels like powershell should have nicer way to do this.

```
$test = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        testProp = "test1"
        testChild = [PSCustomObject]@{
            id = 1
            name = "test name 1"
        }
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        testProp = "test2"
        testChild = [PSCustomObject]@{
            id = 2
            name = "test name 2"
        }
    }
)

$result = $test | select testProp, testChild | % {
    $_.testChild = [PSCustomObject]@{
        id = $_.testChild.id
    }
    $_
}

$result
```

This outputs:

```
testProp testChild
-------- ---------
test1    @{id=1}  
test2    @{id=2}
```

Which is exactly what I want. I'd be nice if I could do something like this:

```
$result = $test | select testProp, testChild.id
```

Bearing in mind that I do not want flat properties returned - I want the original object with some properties removed / only the properties I specify included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this *with* `Select-Object`:

```
$result = $test | select testProp, @{
    Name = 'id'
    Expression = { $_.testChild.id }
}
```

Basically, `Select-Object` allows you to define your own properties, where the value is determined by an expression (a `[ScriptBlock]`), so you can run any code you want to determine the value. Within the block, `$_` refers to the "current object" the same way it would in a `ForEach-Object` call.

Comment: Thanks. That still feels fairly long-winded (and actually produces /more/ code than my example in my use-case - mostly because I'm manipulating arrays for some properties). I'll accept this if no one else comes up with anything neater!

Comment: Actually, your answer does not do what I specified - you've returned a flat `id` property. It needs to be an object as per my example.

Comment: @Spikeh you can make the expression its own `Select-Object` statement, which will keep it an object, or you can make the expression create a `[PSObject]` directly as you were doing before. There are several ways, but there's nothing that directly gives you the exact result you want